# Understanding いい感じに作用した

Tags: grammar, meaning

> 「ど、どういうことだ？治ってたって……何が？」
>
> 「だから、真那の身体がです。DEMにさんざっぱら弄くり回されたダメージが、嘘みたいに消えてやがっていたそうです。仮説ですが、澪さんの霊結晶が弾けた際の霊力の波が、こう、**いい感じに作用したんじゃねーかと**。健康に気を遣えば白寿も夢じゃねーと言われました」

I’m have some trouble understanding the bold part (especially the いい感じに part). It seems to literally mean “I think it comfortably affected my body”, which makes little sense. Or should I understand it as “It made my body comfortable”? If so, what would be the function of the に?

Answer (score 2):

That いい感じ has little to do with comfort or a good feeling. いい感じに作用した simply means it worked (on the body) nicely, or in a positive way. It’s not much different from いいように作用した, except it’s colloquial.